# Is it true, that $(a:b) \cdot 2=a:(b:2)$, when b is even?

Tags: real-analysis

I was doing my maths homework and I found that $(a:b) \cdot 2=a:(b:2)$ when b is even!I tried to improve it with examples, but I am not sure if it is true.Can you put it to the test and tell me if I have found a formula!

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: The colon (:) denotes division. The dot (.) multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true for any number and can be proven using the associativity of the product (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property). You just have to consider that dividing is the same as multiplying by the inverse of any number.

In your particular situation:

$$(a/b) \cdot 2=(a \cdot 1/b) \cdot 2 = a \cdot (2 \cdot 1/b) = a \cdot (2/b) = \frac{a}{b/2}$$

The only thing is that $b/2$ is an integer only when $b$ is even.

Comment: Chances are OP does not know about fractions.

Comment: So did I found something new?

Comment: @preslav No, not really.

Answer (score 2):

It is in fact true for all $a,b$ but if $b$ is odd, then you will get a non-integer in the denominator. In fact a more general statement is true:

> $$a :(b:c)=(a:b)\times c$$

To see this, note that I can multiply with $c : c$, which is just 1.

$$a :(b:c) \times c:c =(a:b)\times c$$

But as you probably know, we do denominator times denominator and numerator times numerator when multiplying fractions. So we get

$$(a\times c) :(b:c \times c) =(a:b)\times c$$

$$(a\times c) :b =(a:b)\times c$$

$$(a:b)\times c =(a:b)\times c$$

which is clearly true. When you are formally writing a proof, you should write this form the end to the beginning, but I think this is easier for you to understand.